# How to prove two events is independent?

Tags: probability, independence

I have quesion: A, B, C is independent. How to show that $P(A^c)$ and $P(B^c\cup C^c)$ are independent?

I do some prove like this:

= $P(A^c\cap B^c)\cup P(A^c\cap C^c)$

= $P(A^c)P(B^c)\cup P(A^c)P(C^c)$

And I was stuck here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A^{c}=A^{c} \cap [(B^{c}\cup C^{c})]\cup [A^{c}\cap [B\cap C]$. So $P(A^{c} \cap [(B^{c}\cup C^{c}))=P(A^{c})-P(A^{c}\cap [B\cap C])$ Next you can show that $P(A^{c}\cap [B\cap C])=P(A^{c})P( [B\cap C])$. So we get $P(A^{c} \cap [(B^{c}\cup C^{c}])=P(A^{c})-P(A^{c})P( [B\cap C])=P(A^{c}) P(B^{c}\cup C^{c})$